# Vue Component for each showing no output in Laravel blade

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8

excuse my
I have an **PostController** and an **PostList.vue**.

Im trying to cast my **Posts** database in my **PostList.vue -> Welcome.blade.php**. But i don't get any output at all. And yes the component is properly registered, if i write normal text in the component it will show up.

PostList.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>dwad
        <div class="card mb-2" v-for="post in posts" v-bind:key="post.id">
            <div class="card-body ">
                <h4 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h4>
                <p class="card-text">{{ post.body }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                posts: []
            };
        },

        created() {
            this.getPosts();
        },

        methods: {
            getPosts(api_url) {
                api_url = api_url || '/api/posts';
                fetch(api_url)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(response => {
                        this.posts = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err));
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

PostController.php

```
public function index_vue(){
        // Get the posts
        $posts = Posts::paginate(5);
        // Return collection of posts as a resource
        return PostResource::collection($posts);
}
```

Welcome.blade.php

```
<div id="app">
        <navbar></navbar>
        <post-list></post-list>
</div>
```

api.php

```
Route::get('posts', [PostController::class, 'index_vue']);
```

Comment: may be your `/api/posts` retrun empty data

Comment: sorry sir, i was eating. 
Its not empty, if i go to localhost/api/posts it will show everything in json format.

Comment: did you check vue devtools in this vairable `posts`